# Null troubles with PowerShell AD script for creating new users

Tags: powershell, null, active-directory

Been smooth sailing with creating users for my domain, now I'm trying to set the uidNumber based on what the last 4 digits of the generated objectSid. Might be a simple solution but hoping for some help.

The rest of the code runs fine until we get to the '$last4' variable so I snipped to make it shorter, but if putting the whole script helps, happy to do so.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$firstname = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the first name"
$lastname = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the last name"

$location = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter user location (LA/NY)"
$path = "OU=Users,OU=$location,OU=GS,DC=random,DC=com"

New-ADUser `
   -snip

Add-ADGroupMember `
    -Identity "$snip" -Members $username

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username

$objectSid = $user.objectSid

$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $objectSid.Substring($objectSid.Length - 4)
$newUidNumber = "71$last4DigitsOfObjectSid"

Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Replace @{'uidNumber'=$newUidNumber}
```

Error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\newtry.ps1:31 char:1
>
> - $last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $objectSid.Substring($objectSid.Length - 4)
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectSid` is not an attribute that `Get-ADUser` returns by default, the attribute you're looking for is just `SID`. `$objectSid` in your snippet is actually null, hence the error you're having.

Also, `Substring` is a String method and `SID` and `objectSid` are instances of [`SecurityIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=net-7.0). This class does not have a `Substring` method. You would need to refer to the [`.Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.value?view=net-7.0#system-security-principal-securityidentifier-value):

```
$sid = $user.SID
$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $sid.Value.Substring($sid.Value.Length - 4)
```

A much easier way of getting the last 4 digits would be with `-replace` which will coerce the `SecurityIdentifier` to a string before replacing:

```
$sid = $user.SID
$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = $sid -replace '.+(?=.{4}$)'
```

Or using `-split` which would also work for SIDs having less than 4 digits:

```
$last4DigitsOfObjectSid = ($sid -split '-')[-1]
```

Comment: Clearly explained thanks so much, it's now working